# Selenium Grid Implementaiton with exisiting framework produce an Null pointer exception

Tags: java, selenium

We have implemented the Selenium Grid (Distributed Test) Concept with our existing framework, while implemented its produce an Null Pointer Exception
as of now i have an single package, with three class file (Baseclass, Loginclass, testcase)

Baseclass - getting my desired driver and navigate to application

```
class Baseclass {
    public WebDriver myDriver;
    public static String baseUrl;

    // Explicit Constructors
    public Baseclass() {
        baseUrl = "https://example.com/";
    }
    public void Navigate(String url) {
        String navigateToThisUrl = baseUrl + url;       
        myDriver.navigate().to(navigateToThisUrl);
    }
    public void GetDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
        threadDriver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, fp);
        desiredCapabilities.setBrowserName(DesiredCapabilities.firefox()
                .getBrowserName());
        myDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(
                "http://localhost:5555/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
    }
    }
```

and in Loginclass navigate to the location (either QA or UAT etc.,)

```
public class Loginclass extends Baseclass {

    public Loginclass navigateToLogin() {
        Navigate("qa");
        return new Loginclass();
    }
    }
```

Testcase we have an test case and executed the same

```
public class TestcaseSearch extends Loginclass {
    @BeforeTest
    public final void Startup() throws MalformedURLException {
        Baseclass baseClass = new Baseclass();
        baseClass.GetDriver;        
        }       
    @Test
    public void fieldsSearch(String username, String password)
            throws Exception {      
        Loginclass loginClass = new Loginclass();
        navigateToLogin();
        }
        }
```

While Execute the above its produce an Null Pointer Exception

Baseclass: `idsDriver.navigate().to(navigateToThisUrl);`

Loginclass :`Navigate("qa");`

Let me know how can i rectify this

Exception output

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.Baseclass.Navigate(Baseclass.java:11)
    at com.Loginclass.Navigate(Loginclass.java:1)
    at com.TestcaseSearch.Navigate(TestcaseSearch.java:1)
    at com.Loginclass.navigateToLogin(Loginclass.java:4)
    at com.TestcaseSearch.fieldsSearch(TestcaseSearch.java:11)
```

Comment: Can you show where the NPE occurs, and include a full stack trace?

Comment: Don't set static fields in constructors: you are resetting `baseUrl` every time you create an instance.

Comment: Why are you creating a `new Baseclass` inside `TestcaseSearch`, a subclass of `Baseclass`?

Comment: @Andy stack trace java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.Baseclass.Navigate(Baseclass.java:11)
 at com.Loginclass.Navigate(Loginclass.java:1)
 at com.TestcaseSearch.Navigate(TestcaseSearch.java:1)
 at com.Loginclass.navigateToLogin(Loginclass.java:4)
 at com.TestcaseSearch.FieldsSearch(TestcaseSearch.java:11)

Comment: please put that in your question, where you can format it legibly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `myDriver` instance is null because you create a new instance of `Baseclass` in `Startup()`, which sets `myDriver` on itself rather than the actual test class instance.

Similarly, you don't need to create a new `Loginclass` in `fieldsSearch`, because `TestcaseSearch` is a subclass of `Loginclass`:

```
public class TestcaseSearch extends Loginclass {
    @BeforeTest
    public final void Startup() throws MalformedURLException {
        GetDriver();        
    }       

    @Test
    public void fieldsSearch(String username, String password)
            throws Exception {      
        navigateToLogin();
    }
}
```